# MySQL connection lost: system error: 110

Tags: mysql, connection

I am trying to connect to my mySQL server through localhost on my dedicated server, but I keep getting the error:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 110
```

CODE:

```
<?php

$link = mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '****'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
}
```

I haven't configured a firewall, so all ports should be open. What do I need to do? I have already checked several other similar questions, but none of them solved my problem. **I am not connecting remotely**.

**UPDATE**

Okay I found the issue with the connection to the server (I was connecting twice). I am able to connect now to the server, but when I run any query, the server returns FALSE. I have used this code before and it has worked before, but now that I have changed servers, it is not working.

Thanks,

David

Comment: What does `perror 110` tell you?

Comment: All I know is that it's a timeout, but I don't know why I can't connect.

Comment: Can you connect using command line tools? mysql -u someuser -p

Comment: I am not trying to connect remotely. However, if I try to connect through port 3306 on Terminal, the connection times out as well.

Comment: are you sure your mysql server is running? And running on the right port? Double check that it is bound to all IP addresses or at least to the localhost, maybe it is bound to external IP address only?

Comment: Please check my update to the question

Comment: Same query works in mysql command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be you are connecting to your db with different parameters

Comment: I actually was connecting twice and was connecting with the wrong user (not the root user). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error code of "110" on server A. Have never changed the credentials, etc on both server A and B. However, my issue was that one server is actually communicating via the MySQL port: 3306 of server B, and I have recently setup firewall on server B, to allow remote MySQL access from server A. Server A was trying to connect to the Server B MySQL port 3306 and webserver would just timeout, issuing the MySQL error code and line error on the code.

Solution that worked for me is:
**sudo ufw status**

Check if MySQL port is in the list, if not do this:
**sudo ufw allow mysql**

This will add the ip4 and ip6 rules into the firewall approved list.

Good luck!