# Failed connection with Ensembl VEP script on port 3337

Tags: mysql, bioinformatics

I'm using the VEP (Variant Effect Predictor) standalone Perl script to annotate some variants, it connects to the Ensembl MySql database.
I used the same script before and I didn't have any problems.
But now I'm getting this error:

> DBI connect('host=ensembldb.ensembl.org;port=3337','anonymous',...)
>   failed: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading authorization
>   packet', system error: 110 at
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/Bio/EnsEMBL/Registry.pm line
>   1769.
>
> -------------------- EXCEPTION -------------------- MSG: Cannot connect to the Ensembl MySQL server at ensembldb.ensembl.org:3337;
>   check your settings & DBI error message: Lost connection to MySQL
>   server at 'reading authorization packet', system error: 110 STACK
>   Bio::EnsEMBL::Registry::load_registry_from_db
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/Bio/EnsEMBL/Registry.pm:1769
>   STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::BaseVEP::registry
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/BaseVEP.pm:252
>   STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::BaseRunner::setup_db_connection
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/BaseRunner.pm:120
>   STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::init
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:118
>   STACK Bio::EnsEMBL::VEP::Runner::run
>   /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/modules/Bio/EnsEMBL/VEP/Runner.pm:194
>   STACK toplevel /home/sara/Documenti/bin/vep/ensembl-vep/vep:224 Date
>   (localtime)    = Thu Aug  2 11:30:01 2018

Using port 3306 instead of port 3337 everything works fine. But I need to use port 3337 in order to use human GRCh37 reference genome, while port 3306 is for GRCh38.

I'm working form Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS and the firewall is inactive.

Any suggestions on what can be the problem?

Comment: Maybe this is helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12738346/mysql-connection-lost-system-error-110#

Comment: Any firewall active in the middle?

Comment: I guess so, but I'm working under a company network so I don't know the details. I was hoping to find a solution before contacting the network administrator. What seems strange to me is that some weeks ago this was working properly, and I think that nothing changed in the network settings since then.

Comment: I asked to the network administrator and I can confirm that the firewall is not blocking port 3337. Any suggestions?